# Mysql Query for Calculate 0,4,8,16% taxes

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have query that calculate the zero,four,eight and sixteen percent taxes from database and view it in Report ,it's work OK with small database but when database get huge number of records its take too much time to process and generate the report ,So i would like you to check it and try to solution problem if can ,thanks in advance .

this is my Query;

```
SELECT sales_point.serial,sales_point.date,sales_point.tax,
ROUND(SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(sales_point_transaction.total)
FROM sales_point_transaction
WHERE sales_point_transaction.serial_sales_point = sales_point.serial AND 
sales_point_transaction.taxes = 0.0),0)),3) AS taxNo0,
ROUND(SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(sales_point_transaction.total)
FROM sales_point_transaction
WHERE sales_point_transaction.serial_sales_point = sales_point.serial AND 
sales_point_transaction.taxes = 0.04),0)),3) AS taxNo4,
ROUND(SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(sales_point_transaction.total)
FROM sales_point_transaction
WHERE sales_point_transaction.serial_sales_point = sales_point.serial AND 
sales_point_transaction.taxes = 0.08),0)),3) AS taxNo8,
ROUND(SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(sales_point_transaction.total) 
FROM sales_point_transaction
WHERE sales_point_transaction.serial_sales_point = sales_point.serial AND 
sales_point_transaction.taxes = 0.16),0)),3) AS taxNo16,
ROUND(SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(sales_point_transaction.total) 
FROM sales_point_transaction
WHERE sales_point_transaction.serial_sales_point = sales_point.serial AND 
sales_point_transaction.taxes = 0.0),0))
+SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(sales_point_transaction.total) 
FROM sales_point_transaction
WHERE sales_point_transaction.serial_sales_point = sales_point.serial AND 
sales_point_transaction.taxes = 0.04),0))
+SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(sales_point_transaction.total) 
FROM sales_point_transaction
WHERE sales_point_transaction.serial_sales_point = sales_point.serial AND   
sales_point_transaction.taxes = 0.08),0))
+SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(sales_point_transaction.total)
FROM sales_point_transaction
WHERE sales_point_transaction.serial_sales_point = sales_point.serial AND   
sales_point_transaction.taxes = 0.16),0))+ tax,3) AS total
FROM sales_point
WHERE sales_point.date between "2013-08-10"  AND "2014-09-30"
GROUP BY serial
```

This's EXPLAIN

```
+----+--------------------+-------------------------+-------+---------------------+---------+----
|id|select_type| table       | type  | possible_keys  | key    |key_len |ref |rows| Extra    |
+----+--------------------+-------------------------+-------+---------------------+---------+----
|1|PRIMARY      | sales_point | index | PRIMARY,userForeign | PRIMARY |4|NULL|9163| Using where |
|9|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY |sales_point_transaction|ALL| NULL|NULL| NULL| NULL|13528| Using where |
|8|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY |sales_point_transaction|ALL| NULL|NULL| NULL| NULL|13528| Using where |
|7|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY |sales_point_transaction|ALL| NULL|NULL| NULL| NULL|13528| Using where |
|6|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY |sales_point_transaction|ALL| NULL|NULL| NULL| NULL|13528| Using where |
|5|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY |sales_point_transaction|ALL| NULL|NULL| NULL| NULL|13528| Using where |
|4|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY |sales_point_transaction|ALL| NULL|NULL| NULL| NULL|13528| Using where |
|3|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY |sales_point_transaction|ALL| NULL|NULL| NULL| NULL|13528| Using where |
|2|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY |sales_point_transaction|ALL| NULL|NULL| NULL| NULL|13528| Using where |
+----+--------------------+-------------------------+-------+---------------------+---------+----
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: please attach EXPLAIN ALL on a given query

Comment: there's the EXPLAIN for query

Comment: what about splitting that one query into multiple smaller queries which are at least easier to read? So that explain doesn't generate many dependent subqueries